# How to get the data of a category in my catalog?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I use these lines to get the data of a **product** in the catalog,

```
// Get product data.
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product_id = Mage::registry('product')->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product_id);
```

What about if I want to get the data of a **category** in the catalog?

```
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getThumbnail();
```

I get this error,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   ...\default\template\page\html\banner-category.phtml on line 4

I tried with these as well but the same error,

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category_id = Mage::registry('category')->getId();
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id)->getThumbnail();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hi this will work on product details page only,

```
$_category_id = $_product_id->getCategoryIds();
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id)->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get category from product model. refer following link:

[[How to get the category name in product/view.phtml from product_viewed.phtml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520042/how-to-get-the-category-name-in-product-view-phtml-from-product-viewed-phtml?answertab=oldest#tab-top][1])

after that you have top load model of category as

```
$cat=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catIds[0]);
```

now you can use attribute of category as

```
echo $cat->getThumbnail();
```