# How to get the category name in product/view.phtml from product_viewed.phtml?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How can I get the category name from product_viewed.phtml list?

I get an error when I land on the product page `frontend\base\default\template\catalog/product/view.phtml`

if I click a product from `frontend\base\default\template\reports/product_viewed.phtml`

This is the code on my `view.phtml`

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category_detail = Mage::registry('current_category');
var_dump($_category_detail->getName()); //gives current  category name
?>
```

This is the error I get,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in
>   C:\xxx\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml on
>   line 86

But I don't have this error, if I click the product from `frontend\base\default\template\catalog/product/list.phtml`

Any idea how can I get the **category name** from these two different situations?

Comment: Why do you need this? I think it is wrong to do so on product page. If you want to show next and previous product from category page, then it is better to save product IDs to session and show it on product page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can get the category id from product name or id by loading model of product.

such as following code.

```
  $catCollection = $_product->getCategoryCollection();
    foreach($catCollection as $cat){
      print_r($cat->getData());
      //echo $cat->getName();
      //echo $cat->getUrl();
    }
```

Another Way,

```
$_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$catIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

After that you can get the categories by accessing $catIds array such as $catIds[0], $catIds[1] etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get `Mage::registry('current_category')` on `catalog/product/view.phtml` if you access a product with direct link. But if you follow the proper channel like, click on any category then select a product, this particular category will get registered.
You should use the following code where ever you are displaying the categories name:

```
     if(Mage::registry('current_category')){
        echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
     }else{
        $categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
                          ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            echo $category->getName();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

tealou,

`Mage::registry('current_category'`) depends on Product url if product url have category  id in this  routing url ,then you get `Mage::registry('current_category')`,else you `did not get` Mage::registry('current_category') value.
It is logic of url_rewrite feature.

Suppose  you have product testing(id 235 ) and it categories `catone(id 5),cattwo(id 7),catthree (id 11)`

for product url

```
testing.html and target path is catalog/product/view/id/235/

catone/testing.html and target path is catalog/product/view/id/235/category/5
cattwo/testing.html and  target path is catalog/product/view/id/235/category/7
catthree /testing.html and  target path is catalog/product/view/id/235/category/11
```

First url not  have  categoryid so if you click on this url from any category page is not give any value `Mage::registry('current_category')`
Other have category it will give `Mage::registry('current_category')` value in view.phtml of product page.

```
Goto Admin>Catalog>Url rewrite manager her you are find this url
```

If want to `Mage::registry('current_category')` then you need to create a new  Mage::registry() varible from /catalog/category/view.phtml i.e category page.

```
$var=Mage::registry('current_category');

Mage::register('some_name', $var);
```

and fetch in catalog/product/view.phtml using

```
$my_var = Mage::registry('some_name');
```

This `some_name` variable will get when if you will come  to product page from category.
put code like

```
  if(Mage::registry('some_name')){
    var_dump(Mage::registry('some_name'))->getName()); 
//gives current  category name
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not get current category on product page b\c one product can have many categories. What if customer comes to your product page from google.com, for example? What category will this be?

There is no such Mage::registry('current_category') variable on product page. Forget it. This variable exists only on category pages. On product page you can only check if product is in some category.

Answer (score 1):

almost as MTM has been said, I use this:

```
if(Mage::registry('current_category')){
    $catid = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);
} else {
    //because sometimes we can not use registry('current_category'), so we use:
    $cat_ids = $_product->getCategoryIds(); // get all categories where the product is located
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load( $cat_ids[0] ); // load first category
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i use in Magento 1.8

```
<?php $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
     foreach ($cats as $category_id) { $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
     echo $_cat->getName();
}?>
```